# Troubles installing @types/mysql2

Tags: typescript

I'm making an excersice of a CRUD app with typescript. To do a Pool @types/mysql2 is needed but it's actually not working. Somebody knows how to install?. I've been searching in github but the ways published there don´t work. Is any other way to install?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain _but it's actually not working_ in detail? Quick lookup: there is no package [`@types/mysql2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/mysql2) on npm.

Comment: PS C:\Users\LUIS\Desktop\Ejemplo_Typescript> npm i @types/mysql2 -D
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fmysql2 - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@types/mysql2@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

Comment: As pzaenger said, the repository simply doesn't exist which is why you're getting a 404. However, it looks like it's hosted elsewhere: https://github.com/types/mysql2

Answer (score 8):

There is no "@types/mysql2" module on npm.

If you want to use the "mysql2" from your TypeScript project, just installing ["mysql2"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) will fix your problem.
`npm install mysql2`

---

FYI, you may not need ['types/mysql2' module](https://github.com/types/mysql2) anymore.

Because the "mysql2" module supports TS from [v2.2.5](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/releases/tag/v2.2.5)

This could be a reason the "@types/mysql2" is not on the npm and no longer publish its updates.

Check [this commit](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/commit/9c20c3e0a1301a8d68d7f6843205814215020d72) for details about TS supporting works from the "mysql2" module.

But if you still do want to use "types/mysql2",
try
`typings install --save mysql2`
or
`npm install --save-dev types/mysql2#semver:version` as described on [README](https://github.com/types/mysql2/blob/master/README.md) of that module.

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are a great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 4):

I entered it as follows:

`npm i --save-dev types/mysql2#`

The following content is added to the package.json file:

```
"devDependencies": {
   "@types/mysql2": "github:types/mysql2",
}
```

Comment: I am getting  `Could not install from "node_modules/@types/mysql2/@types/mysql@github:types/mysql" as it does not contain a package.json file.` today and I don't know why

Comment: I don't think this is required anymore.